# In WinDbg commands, how can I refer to a register with the same name as a global variable?

Tags: debugging, windbg

Suppose I want to debug this program using the WinDbg, cdb, or ntsd debuggers for Windows:

```
/* test.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int rip = 42;

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world!");
    return (0);
}
```

I compile the program for AMD64 and run it under WinDbg. I set a breakpoint at main(), and when the breakpoint hits, I want to inspect the value at the RIP register (program counter), and the memory around that value if the value is treated as a pointer.

I can see the value of the register directly with `r rip`, but when I try to look at the memory around that address, WinDbg shows me a different address! Having read the symbols in test.pdb, WinDbg sees that `rip` is a global variable declared in the C code and shows me the memory around `&rip`.

```
0:000> bu test!main

0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
test!main:
00007ff6`de1868d0 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h

0:000> r rip
rip=00007ff6de1868d0

0:000> db rip
00007ff6`de1f2000  2a 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff-01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  *...............
00007ff6`de1f2010  01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00-ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ................
00007ff6`de1f2020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-43 46 92 e5 1b df 00 00  ........CF......
00007ff6`de1f2030  bc b9 6d 1a e4 20 ff ff-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ..m.. ..........
00007ff6`de1f2040  00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00-ca b0 1e de f6 7f 00 00  ................
00007ff6`de1f2050  00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00  ................
00007ff6`de1f2060  d0 66 fc c2 f2 01 03 00-ab 90 ec 5e 22 c0 b2 44  .f.........^"..D
00007ff6`de1f2070  a5 dd fd 71 6a 22 2a 15-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...qj"*.........

0:000> ? rip
Evaluate expression: 140698265264128 = 00007ff6`de1f2000

0:000> ? dwo(rip)
Evaluate expression: 42 = 00000000`0000002a
```

This is really annoying, but as long as I'm aware of it, it isn't a problem when manually reading data like this. But if I want to *use* the register value, for example in scripting the debugger, then there is no easy workaround:

```
0:000> bu test!main ".if (dwo(rip) == 0n42) { .echo Whoops! I don't want to get here! }"

0:000> g
Whoops! I don't want to get here!
test!main:
00007ff6`de1868d0 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
```

This problem, that symbols in the program hide register names, makes things really difficult for me. An actual scenario this broke:

1. I wanted to set a breakpoint on CreateFileW(), a very commonly called Windows API function.
2. Since I only cared about one particular file, I wanted to inspect the filename, which is passed in the RCX register, and continue past the breakpoint unless the filename matched the file I wanted.
3. But I couldn't write this condition, because another module in the program defined a symbol `foobar!rcx`, and any references to `rcx` I make in the command to execute on the breakpoint refer to that global variable!

So how do I tell WinDbg that yes, I really meant to read the register? And what if I want to write that register? There must be a simple thing I am missing here.

Comment: if dwo(@rip) == xx do some thing else if qwo (@rcx) != foobar!rcx do some other thing .else gotosleep() @rcx = register rcx whereeas foobar!rcx or simply rcx is a global

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in passing by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826130/is-there-a-way-in-windbg-to-create-a-break-point-that-will-fire-when-a-certain-p), you can put an at sign (`@`) in front of a register name to force it to be interpreted as a register or pseudo-register, bypassing the attempt to parse it as a hexadecimal number or a symbol.

> [**Registers and Pseudo-Registers in MASM Expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552157(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> You can use registers and pseudo-registers within MASM expressions. **You can add an at sign (@) before all registers and pseudo-registers.** The at sign causes the debugger to access the value more quickly. This at sign is unnecessary for the most common x86-based registers. For other registers and pseudo-registers, we recommend that you add the at sign, but it is not actually required. If you omit the at sign for the less common registers, the debugger tries to parse the text as a hexadecimal number, then as a symbol, and finally as a register.

Comment: I'd go further and say that since it's faster in MASM syntax (and this can be significantly faster, for example if you can skip searching a symbol in all your modules, one of which is Chrome's 900MB PDB) and mandatory in C++ syntax, it's a good practice to **always** prepend register names with '@'. I do it almost automatically now, and every time I forget it and stare at the `*BUSY*` message (even for only a few extra seconds) I beat myself up for this.

Comment: @conio Absolutely. The `@` is instinctive for me, too.